# При resize python вылитает

Tags: python, pil

При попытке resize изображения питон вылитает, в чем может быть проблема?
Код:

```
>>> from PIL import Image  
>>> in_f = "/path/3azle2cw1ovrmuhs5bt7.png"  
>>> im = Image.open(in_f)  
>>> im.resize((30, 20))  
Killed
```

PIL много раз переустанавливал, раньше ресайзелись маленькие изображения, теперь вовсе все перестало ресайзить. Ошибок никаких не выдает, просто вылетает с надписью Killed, не могу вообще понять в чем проблема и куда копать.
Локально установлен питон, та же версия PIL и все работает отлично.

Answer (score 2):

На форуме подсказали что проблема может быть в нехватки ОЗУ на сервере, после проверки, опасения подтвердились. 
Если пробую малый файл ресайзить все отлично, как только кидаю файл в 7Мб, то ОЗУ кончается и процесс питона закрывается.
Буду настраивать другие программы, чтобы меньше ОЗУ хвалаи, дабы осталось что-то для обжимки фоток.